# Unable to remove the notice in opencart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I installed opencart and database for it . Default theme of the opencart works fine but when i upload the new theme , it is showing warnings

```
Notice: Undefined variable: position in /home/gadgets/public_html/site/catalog/view/theme/projectstore/template/module/featured.tpl on line 1
Notice: Undefined variable: position in /home/gadgets/public_html/site/catalog/view/theme/projectstore/template/module/featured.tpl on line 1
Notice: Undefined variable: position in /home/gadgets/public_html/site/catalog/view/theme/projectstore/template/module/featured.tpl on line 93
Notice: Undefined variable: position in home/gadgets/public_html/site/catalog/view/theme/projectstore/template/module/featured.tpl on line 93
```

I dont know what else to do .Theme is working fine just it showing these warnings , is there any way to hide this or remove this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set your error reporting to 0. That is not a solution, it's just covering up the issue which is still going to be happening. What you need to do is get in touch with your theme developer and ask them to fix the error. This is most likely due to the theme being incompatible with your store version, but could simply be an issue the developer overlooked when creating the theme